# Screen Tearing Problems in fullscreen

Tags: arch-linux

I have been experiencing this problem for a long time. I watch a lot of media with different codecs on my machine. And there will always be this screen tearing problem when I put it in full screen. While it is a so much less noticeable in border to border window mode, it is negligible.

I tried different players like mpv and vlc. Edited the mpv config to the following:

```
profile=gpu-hq
blend-subtitles=yes
video-sync=display-resample
interpolation=yes
tscale=box
tscale-window=quadric #(or "sphinx")
tscale-radius=1.0 #lower (e.g. 0.955) = sharper; higher (e.g. 1.005) = smoother 
tscale-clamp=0.0
```

But the problem still persists. Though with less intensity.

So I would like some help and input from the community, to see your ideas as to how to fix this.

Info:

OS: Linux 5.10.30-1-lts x86_64

GPU: Nvidia 980 Ti

Driver: nvidia-lts 1:465.24.02-2, nvidia-settings 465.24.02-1, nvidia-utils 465.24.02-2

Monitor: DP1.4 cable 1080p

DE: Gnome with X11

Please let me know if you need anything. And thanks for dropping by!

EDIT: This is my monitor: https://www.samsung.com/us/computing/monitors/led/samsung-32-curved-led-monitor-lc32f391fwnxza/

Comment: Are you using `Option      "metamodes" "nvidia-auto-select +0+0 {ForceCompositionPipeline=On, ForceFullCompositionPipeline=On}"` ? If not, please try

Comment: It is on, after a suggestion in reddit, it drastically improved the situation that very little or none remains of it. Though I was wondering why this was one of the reasons?